# Magnolia 5.5 CMS: Mark hotfixes to be removed with next update

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

If I override a resource in Magnolia 5.5 with a quickfix, is there a possibility to mark that resource so that the quickfix will be removed with an update of the source files.

(For example if I make a quickfix and simultaneously I commit a real fix to say svn on an update the resource is still overridden with the quickfix and not with the real fix.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not handled automatically, but it's indeed interesting use case.
You should be able to get that working if you are willing to write bit of Java yourself. Just register for `DirectoryWatcherService` (you will need to implement `info.magnolia.dirwatch.WatcherCallback` to do that). In your callback you will be notified when there are any updates to the light modules and can react on it (e.g. by checking if there is hotfix and removing it on such update). If you want to see implementation of such callback, have a look at [Content Importer Module callback](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/content-importer/browse/src/main/java/info/magnolia/content/observer/TaskCreatorWatcherCallback.java).

HTH,
Jan